# How to output a list of specific products only in Woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How do I output selected products from a Woocommerce Plugin so the list looks the same as a product category list?

Woocommerce has a built-in shortcode `[products]` to output products. I can do that if I create a page, but can I do that programmatically?

e.g. URL is /prods/?custom_key=test (I know how to tell WP to recognise the URL and use my code)

Using WP_Query I set global `$wp_query` to returns a list of products to be outputted.

```
global $wp_query
$args = [...];
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I've tried using the archive page

```
include(get_query_template('archive'));
```

which almost works, but it doesn't display the products like it would in a product category.

After creating `$wp_query`, **how do I output the products by re-using the product loop that the shortcode `[products]` would use**?

Comment: Whoever requested to close with the reason "Needs details or clarity- This question should include more details and clarify the problem", please clarify how what's being asked is unclear

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple product loop that you can use in any template file

```
 <ul class="products">
        <?php
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'product',
                'posts_per_page' => 12
                );
            $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
            if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
                while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                    wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
                endwhile;
            } else {
                echo __( 'No products found' );
            }
            wp_reset_postdata();
        ?>
    </ul><!--/.products-->
```

this utilizes Woocommerce template structure as the shortcode would. you can change your args to what ever you need to pull through